# setState return the old value after promise

Tags: reactjs, promise, setstate

I Saved image file to s3 amazon web service, and after retrieved the link.
When link returned from s3 as a string a try to save it to state.But if we test it in console.log(editedProduct),setEditedProduct every time return the previously value, but I need the new.

```
      const imageSave = async (file: File, fileName: string) => {
         await modalProductUpload(file).then((s3payload) => {
             setEditedProduct({ ...editedProduct, [fileName]: s3payload.Location })
             console.log(s3payload.Location);
         });
         setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(editedProduct);
         }, 6000)
     }
```

Comment: Can you share your whole component?

Answer (score 0):

React would batch set state asynchronously. You could get the updated state in the `useEffect` with having dependency as that state.

```js
useEffect(() => { console.log(editedProduct); }, [editedProduct]);
```